# React hook form useFieldArray not updating fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm facing an issue where the fields from `useFieldArray` (react-form-hook) don't get updated when they are replaced from a `useEffect` hook.

Here's a minimal example that demonstrates it. `MyComponent` creates a field array using a `control` provided from its parent component. The field array doesn't get updated and the items don't get rendered the first time (it does in subsequent renders)

```
const MyComponent = ({ control, items }) => {
  const { fields, append, remove, replace, update } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "items",
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    replace(items)
  }, [items]);

  return (
    <>
      {fields.map((item, index) => (
        <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>
      )}
    </>)
```

This component is inside a parent

```
 const [items, setItems] = useState([])
 const { handleSubmit, control, setValue, getValues, reset, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues
  });

 useEffect(() => {

 ... 
 // items is a list of {id: '', name: ''} objects
 setItems(items); 
 }, [])

 ...
 
 return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(saveData)}>
   <Controller ... > <TextField ... /> </Controller>
   <MyComponent items={items} control={control} getValues={getValues}/>
</>
)
```

`items` always has items (not empty).

What I think happening is that `fields` doesn't get updated at the same time when `replace(items)` is done and due to some (timing?) issue it is always empty.

Any idea what could be happening and how to avoid it?

Sample code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-template-forked-2ll8zb?file=/src/index.js:0-1013

The UI basically creates a field array using `useFieldArray` which receives the `Controller` from a parent component. The field array is rendered and the purpose is to add/remove items dynamically and reflect the changes on screen. Add/remove functionality is not implemented -- the issue occurs in the first render.

Comment: "`items` always has items (not empty)" - `items` is an empty array on the initial render. Also, `setItems(items);` seems a bit useless unless this is a different `items` reference. Think you could [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] so we can see what `defaultValues` is and anything else that wasn't included enough that someone *could* reproduce this on their end?

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese sample code here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-template-forked-2ll8zb?file=/src/index.js:0-1013

Comment: Perhaps my unfamiliarity with `react-hook-form` and this `useFieldArray` hook, but in your sandbox even when doing a double-append (append the same data twice), and/or looping the `items` array twice... the `fields` array *still* only has length 1 and has the last item added. I did the same bit with a third `items` array element added, and only the final `items` element is appended. I don't think this is a React hooks or component lifecycle issue. If I do a force rerender, again only the final element is appended, but now it's a duplicate entry.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain the UI and what you are expecting the code to do? Is there a reason the form data can't be initialized from the start?

Comment: Added some description on what I'm trying to do. This is how it's being used as per the docs https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-ssugn. In my case, I'm using the  `useFieldArray` in a child component with the controller being passed from the parent

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded react-hook-form to the latest version (v7.46.1), and used `replace(items)` instead of `append`, and I think it produced the result you were expecting.

Here's a fork of your sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-template-forked-nlr4wg?file=/src/index.js